# Any alternatives to Google's clearPixel.gif 404 not found?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, 404

I recently noticed the following Google-related error on our website pages:

> GET
>   http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/teracent_product_template_V1/clearPixel.gif
>   404 (Not Found)
>   pagead2.googlesyndication.com/teracent_product_template_V1/clearPixel.gif:1

I'm wondering if this is hindering AdSense clicks from registering with Google.

I'm using the asynch analytics code that begins with:

```
<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are [people complaining about similar issues in the Google product forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/zP-0cay_ne8/TPZ_xAKHNMQJ).

It appears to me to be related to the creative for a Flash based advertisement that wasn't created very carefully.